# fail2ban.ipdns: Unable to find a corresponding IP address for unknown [Errno -2]

Tags: log-files, fail2ban

Was just scanning through my Fail2ban logs on a routine security check. Found the following line occurring a few times over the last 4 days. Should I be concerned? I Googled, but I couldn't find anything on this. Most results at least specify the IP address, not `unknown`.

`YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss fail2ban.ipdns [1269]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for unknown: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

What is a corresponding IP address for unknown? And what is `[Errno -2]`?

Comment: This might be difficult to answer without knowing your jail configuration.

Comment: Errno -2 is equivalent to error 2 (see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848729/why-return-a-negative-errno-e-g-return-eio)[this Q&A] for a discussion of historical reasons behind negative C/POSIX return codes). It seems like the initial _unknown_ value is because whatever regex you have isn't correctly identifying the IP address from the log file, or your application isn't correctly logging the IP address in the first place. Please provide more info in your question, example configs, details of logfiles being scraped, and whether you've updated anything recently.